# Compute a commutative and associative operation on n-2 arguments efficiently

Tags: algorithms, optimization, recursion

Considering a function $f$ such that:
$$ f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = f(f(x_1, x_2), x_3) = f(x_1, f(x_2, x_3)) $$
and
$$ f(x_1, x_2) = f(x_2, x_1) $$

and a set $X = \{ x_1, \dots, x_n \}$; how to compute
$$f(x_1, \dots,  x_{i - 1}, x_{i + 1}, \dots, x_{j-1}, x_{j+1}, \dots, x_n)$$
for all pairs $i, j \in 1, \dots, n$, $i < j$ while minimizing the number of calls to $f$?

- Only $f(x)$ and $f(x, y)$ can be computed
- $f^{-1}$ is not defined

---

For example, let $f$ be addition, i.e, $f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)=x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$. However, only calls to $f$ with one or two arguments are allowed, i.e $f(x)=x$ and $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$. In particular, neither subtraction nor negation is allowed. The problem is to compute all sums of $n-2$ numbers among the given $n$ numbers with the least number of additions. There are $n(n-1)/2$ such sums.

Comment: What kind of function is $f$ that it can take $2$, $3$, or $n$ arguments? Is $f(x_1, x_2) = f(f(x_1), x_2)$?

Comment: @joseville in my case it's a function that computes the cost of a list of elements. The list can have any size

Comment: Is it like an aggregate/accumulator? Or maybe an operator like add where $a + b + c = (a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$?

Comment: Is the base case when the function has just two arguments?

What exactly is the function? What is the value of (1)? How do you compute (1) for example? Can you include this and the above info in the question?

Comment: @joseville yes, it's usually a combination of $+$ and $\max$ where $x$ is a tuple

Comment: @joseville the base case is with a single element

Comment: @joseville it depends on the application. I'm not sure explaining the whole back story here is relevant

Comment: $f(x_1, x_2) = f(x_2, x_1)$ means the function is commutative. Is it also associative? Are the $x_i$ distinct/unique? Can you have $f(1,1,2,3,3,4)$ for example?

Comment: @joseville yes, I think it is associative. $x_i$ are not necessarily unique, but are likely to be in practice. And in practice, it's more often vectors instead of numbers

Comment: Is $f^{-1}(x)$ known and about as costly to compute as $f(x)$?

Comment: @greybeard $f^{-1}$ is not known and might even not be defined

Comment: (yoseville is right about improving the question rather than commenting comments.) This was more promising if $f(f(x_1, x_2), x_3) = f(x_1, f(x_2, x_3))$. Oh wait, there's another comment *think it is associative*.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include all relevant information.  Don't just put it in the comments.  We want questions to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and so people can understand what is being asked without having to read the comments.

Comment: @D.W. I added the information about $f^{-1}$. I don't see anything else relevant in the comments. Please indicate what is missing if you think that there is is still something missing. The question looks perfectly clear to me

Comment: Formally, the problem is either undefined or not answerable.  Mathematically, it is entirely possible that the behavior of $f$ on 4 or more arguments is completely unrelated to its behavior on 3 or less arguments, so the information you have given us is not sufficient.  I suspect $f$ has additional structure that you have not presented in the question.  Perhaps your intention is that $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = f(f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}),x_n) = f(x_1,f(x_2,\dots,x_n))$ for all $n$?  What does it mean to say $f(x)$ can be computed (on a single argument?) and how is that relevant?

Comment: Perhaps you mean that it is a [binary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) that is commutative and associative?  Does it have any other properties?  e.g.: is it idempotent?  Is it over a semigroup, monoid, or group?  Is there an identity?  What is the domain of it?  Does it have inverse elements?

Comment: The "(1,…,−1,+1,…,−1,+1,…,) for all pairs ,∈1,…,,  <" was much harder to understand than just saying "The problem is to compute all sums of −2 numbers among the given  numbers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You can compute $f(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1})$ for all $i$ with $n-2$ calls to $f$.  (Simply iterate over $i:=1,\dots,n$.)

(2) Then, using (1), you can compute $f(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots,x_{j-1})$ for all $i,j$ with $n(n-1)/2$ more calls to $f$.  (For each $i$, iterate over $j:=i+2,\dots,n$.)

(3) You can also compute $f(x_{j+1},\dots,x_n)$ for all $j$ with another $n-2$ calls to $f$.  (Iterate over $j:=n,\dots,1$.)

(4) Finally, using (2) and (3), you can compute $f(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},\dots,x_n)$ for all $i,j$ with another $n(n-1)/2$ calls to $f$.

In all, this uses about $n^2+n$ calls to $f$.

This is within a factor of 2 of the best possible, as you need to output $n(n-1)/2$ different values, so obviously you'll need to make at least $n(n-1)/2$ calls to $f$.

Answer (score 1):

(Motivation: let $h = n/2$.
Given $f_{ih} = f(x_i\dots x_{h-1}) \text{ and } f_{hj} = f(x_h\dots x_j)$ (precomputed in about $n$ evaluations of $f$),
$f(x_{i+1}\dots x_{j-1})$ can be computed as $f(f_{(i+1)h}, f_{h(j-1)})$ for all $i\lt h\lt j$.
This saves ?$\frac{(n-2)(n-3)} 2 - n$? evaluations.
Similarly for $q = n/4, 3q = h+q, o = n/8, 3o = q+o, 5o = h+o, 7o = 3q+o, \dots$.)

---

The above promises to be a bookkeeping headache.
Instead, pre-compute $f(x_{k2^l}\dots x_{(k+1)2^l-1}), 0<l\le\lg_2(n), 0<k<\frac n {2^l}$ in about n evaluations of $f$:
Any $f_{ij}$ can be computed in less than $2\lg_2(n)$ evaluations.

### An example

Let $f_{\boxed {lk}} := f(x_{k2^l}\dots x_{(k+1)2^l-1})$

Suppose $n = 13$, then $\lg_2(n) \approx 3.7$. Since $l$ is an integer and $0 < l \leq 3.7...$), this means $l$ iterates through $1, 2, 3$.

### $l = 1,\quad 2^l = 2$

$0 < k < \frac n {2^l} = \frac {13} 2 = 6.5$

So $k$ iterates from $1$ to $6$ inclusive

$$
k=1,\quad f_{\boxed {11}} = f(x_2, x_3)\\
k=2,\quad f_{\boxed {12}} = f(x_4, x_5)\\
k=3,\quad f_{\boxed {13}} = f(x_6, x_7)\\
k=4,\quad f_{\boxed {14}} = f(x_8, x_9)\\
k=5,\quad f_{\boxed {15}} = f(x_{10}, x_{11})\\
k=6,\quad f_{\boxed {16}} = f(x_{12}, x_{13})\\
$$

### $l = 2,\quad 2^l = 4$

$0 < k < \frac n {2^l} = \frac {13} 4 = 3.25$

So $k$ iterates from $1$ to $3$ inclusive

$$
k=1,\quad f_{\boxed {21}} = f(x_4 \dots x_7)\\
k=2,\quad f_{\boxed {22}} = f(x_8 \dots x_{11})\\
k=3,\quad f_{\boxed {23}} = f(x_{12} \dots x_{15})\\
$$

### $l = 3,\quad 2^l = 8$

$0 < k < \frac n {2^l} = \frac {13} 8 = 1.625$

So $k$ iterates from $1$ to $1$

$$k=1,\quad f_{\boxed {31}} = f(x_8 \dots x_{15})$$

Comment: (The mechanism is much the same [joseville](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/152494/19966) was getting at, just usefulness of the results is guaranteed rather than unlikely.)

Comment: Added an example using the limits on $k$ and $l$ you set, but they produce invalid ranges. Either I made a mistake or the limits on  and  (probably just ) need to be tweaked slightly. I think the right limit for  might be 0≤<⌊ $\frac n {2^l}$ ⌋ with $f_{\boxed {lk}}$ defined as $f_{\boxed {lk}} := f(x_{k2^l + 1} \dots x_{(k+1)2^l})$. The +1 in $x_{k2^l + 1}$ is due to the $x_i$ being 1-indexed.

Comment: But I get the overall concept and I like it. Using "sum" as the operator, basically you want to precompute all non-overlapping $2$-sums, all non-overlapping $4$-sums, all non-overlapping $8$-sums, ..., all non-overlapping $2^l$-sums, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Count how many times each $x_i$ occurs in the argument list.

Suppose $X_1$ is the set of $x_i$ that occur once, $X_2$ is the set of $x_i$ that occur twice, ..., $X_m$ is the set of $x_i$ that occur $m$ times, ... etc.

Suppose $y \in X_j$, eventually you will have to evaluate $f(y)$ $j$ times. So instead of computing $f(y)$ $j$ times, just compute it once and save the result (in a dictionary, map, w/e).

Suppose $X_j = \{a, b, c\}$. You will have to evaluate $f(a, b, c)$ $j$ times. Instead of computing it $j$ times, evaluate it once and save the result.

Suppose $d \in X_{2^p}$ for some integer $p$.
Let

- $d_0 := f(d)$
- $d_1 := f(d, d) = f(f(d), f(d)) = f(d_1, d_1)$
- $d_2 := f(d, d, d, d) = f(f(d, d), f(d, d)) = f(d_1, d_1)$
- ...
- $d_p := f(\underbrace{d, d, ..., d}_{2^p\ \text{times}}) = f(d_{p-1}, d_{p-1})$

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Is it clear that the goal is to compute $n(n - 1)$ values?

Comment: Not at all. You should read through [ask].

I think the above makes sense w.r.t. to what you asked.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  I don't see an algorithm here that produces the desired output.  I don't understand how computing $f(y)$ helps.  I don't understand why we would evaluate $f(a,b,c)$ more than once.  I don't understand how the $d_i$ help or how they are relevant.

Comment: I think I get the idea. In the light of [$x_i$ are not necessarily unique, but are likely to be in practice](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/152493/compute-recursive-function-efficiently/152494#comment320721_152493), it doesn't look helpful.